# Update cookie expires without any change in the value

Tags: asp.net, cookies

How can I simply update the expiry of a cookie on each page request without having any impact on its value ?

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>  'update the User cookie expiration time on every page load
>     Dim cookieName As String = ConfigKeys.UserCookieName
>     Dim cookieExpr As String = ConfigKeys.CookieExpiration.ToString
>
>     '--get the cookies from request object
>     Dim userCookie As HttpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies(cookieName.ToUpper())
>     '--set the expiry date
>     userCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(Integer.Parse(cookieExpr))
>     '--add the updated cookies back to Response object
>     HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(userCookie)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["MyCookie"].Expires =
    DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
```

Or set it to maximum and forget about the expiration:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["MyCookie"].Expires =
    DateTime.MaxValue
```

Comment: I have tried that and while it does change the expiration of the cookie, it also removes the content of the cookie